# ¿Como puedo fijar Labels?

Tags: php, html, visual-studio

tratare de explicarme lo mejor que pueda.
Actualmente estoy ajustado una pagina web, y tengo unos labels que hacen como encabezado para otros, el problema es que cuando desciendo en la pagina los encabezados pues también suben y necesito que todo el tiempo se vean en la parte superior, y he tratado de ajustar eso pero he tenido unos problemas, les adjuntare unas imágenes para que lo vean.

[image: Asi se ve cuando estoy en el top de la pagina]

[image: Esto pasa cuando desciendo]

[image: Este es el código de esos label]

La primer imagen es como se ve cuando estoy en el top de la pagina, la segunda imagen es lo que sucede cuando desciendo y la tercera es el codigo de los label que necesito estáticos.
Les agradecería mucho que me ayuden a dejar esos labels estáticos y que cuando baje se queden fijos en el top para seguirlos viendo a medida que baje.

Comment: Bienvenida para que tus preguntas sean mejor recibidas te invito a leer [ask] y seria mejor que tu codigo no fuera una imagen

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu sugerencia, lo que pasa en que no tengo el código a la mano de momento, pero en cuanto pueda lo subiré

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pienso que usar plugins que ya hacen el trabajo es bastante simple, hay muchos de ellos, acá hago referencia a uno de ellos

https://github.com/markmalek/Fixed-Header-Table

Donde lo único que se debe hacer es:

```
$('selector').fixedHeaderTable({
    footer: true,
    cloneHeadToFoot: true,
    fixedColumn: false 
});
```

selector, es el selector de tu tabla, lo único a tener en cuenta es que la tabla debe ser de la forma:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
          <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

footer hace que puedas poner alguna info en el final de la tabla, cloneHeadToFoot hace que el encabezado también se fije al final de la tabla, fixedColumn hace que la primera columna se fije también, así que el plugin tiene buenas opciones, tiene licencia MIT y un par de métodos útiles. espero sirva de ayuda.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aporte, lo implementare y veré que tal me va, pero eso no es una tabla, son puros labes alineados (así me la dieron cuando) eso me presenta algún inconveniente o lo puedo trabajar normal sin importar que no sea una tabla

Comment: Es que yo veo que los labels están dentro de celdas de una tabla <td>, el plugin funciona para tablas.

Comment: Te lo agradezco mucho, me ha servido mucho tu código.